# how to set default location for uploading files or selecting files in window 8

Tags: window, location, default

hello every and thanks in advance.

how i can set the default location for the choosing file dialog box and uploading file dialog box to a single directory in window 8.

i want to search in c:/somefolder every time when i chose or upload file from any where however it not happen if i select from desktop then next time it also makes the desktop as the default location.
i think window 8 chose the recent location as default location but i don't want that and i want to restrict to same folder even if i upload file from desktop or any where else.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
FileOpenPicker folderPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
folderPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
folderPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
```

you can get the list of locations in PickerLocationId from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.pickers.pickerlocationid.aspx)